# How to know disabled/enabled indexes in PostgreSQL and Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, indexing

I would like to know a list of indexes that disabled/enabled in PostgreSQL and Oracle. Can someone suggest me the query?

I have a query for SQL Server like this

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes I
INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON I.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE I.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
AND I.name IS NOT NULL
AND I.is_disabled = 1`
```

I am looking for a similar query for PostgreSQL and Oracle.

Comment: Note that there are invalid (=broken) indexes in PostgreSQL, but you cannot disable an index.

Comment: Please tag only one DBMS. There won't be a single query that covers both databases.

Comment: I did not ask for one query for both databases.

Comment: so you actually asked two questions - which is something you shouldn't do. If you get two answers (one for Oracle and one for Postgres) which one are you going to accept to mark your question as solved?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if you unset `indisvalid` the index will not be used for querying (this also disables the uniqueness property of UNIQUE indexes). The index will still get updated, which you can independently disable as well.

Comment: @Masklinn Modifying the catalogs is dangerous and unsupported. For example, uniqueness is never checked for invalid indexes, which can lead to data corruption if you enable the index again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for postgres:

```
SELECT
    trel.relname AS table_name,
    irel.relname AS index_name,
    string_agg(a.attname, ', ' ORDER BY c.ordinality) AS columns
FROM pg_index AS i
         JOIN pg_class AS trel ON trel.oid = i.indrelid
         JOIN pg_class AS irel ON irel.oid = i.indexrelid
         JOIN pg_attribute AS a ON trel.oid = a.attrelid
         JOIN LATERAL unnest(i.indkey)
    WITH ORDINALITY AS c(colnum, ordinality)
              ON a.attnum = c.colnum
WHERE i.indisvalid -- WHERE not i.indisvalid
GROUP BY i, trel.relname, irel.relname;
```

Note, that disabling index in postgres means constant updates without it's usage for querying.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me which column indicates index is enabled or not.  I ran the query to select all columns without group by.  Among these columns based on which column I can it is enabled `indisvalid`, `indisready`, `indislive`

Comment: @Jyo: you can't "disable" an index in Postgres. The `indisvalid` and `indisready` are only meaningful for indexes created using `concurrently` **while** they are being created or if creation fails. Once they are successfully created those columns have no meaning any more

Comment: @jyo `indisvalid` indicates whether the index will be used when querying. `indisready` indicates whether it gets updated on table modifications. You can set them explicitely if you have the correct access rights. @a_horse_with_no_name: you absolutely can disable indices in postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you.  I am not looking for query to disable indexes. I just want to check that any indexes disabled during any process. We are facing some issue related to this that is why I want to check this.

Comment: @Jyo if you're trying to see why a query is or is not using an index, this is a decision informed but not solely sourced from indexes being available (in fact since indexes are *mostly* available that's rarely a factor): the planner can decide to skip indices many reasons based on collected statistics & cost estimates. The first is updated by `ANALYZE` / `VACUUM ANALYZE`, the second is part of the postgres configuration. You may also find [the FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_my_queries_slow.3F_Why_don.27t_they_use_my_indexes.3F) useful.

Comment: @Jyo https://gocardless.com/blog/debugging-the-postgres-query-planner/ is also a good walk through the planner's process (for one specific use case).

Answer (score 1):

Use UserIndexes table

```
     select INDEX_NAME, TABLE_OWNER, 
      TABLE_NAME, UNIQUENESS from 
       USER_INDEXES u inner join  
        all_tables a
       On u.table_name=a.table_name
        and u.table_owner=a.owner
```

For all indexes replace the tablename with all_indexes and join dba_tables

Comment: Thank you. Here, which column indicates that index is disabled or enabled.

Comment: Theres no enabled/disabled concept here its just that you can manipulate if u still want the same by `case when index is null then Disabled else Enabled end`

Comment: What "dropped" indicates?  My intention is to check whether indexes disabled when I import db dump.